# SQL: Modify query result rows that have a unique value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a **sqlite** query that returns something like the following with columns [letter, number]:

```
("a", 1) 
("a", 2)
("b", 3)
("c", 3)
```

I want to retrieve the number column as 0 if the letter is distinct.  How is it done?

Expected output:

```
("a", 1) 
("a", 2)
("b", 0)
("c", 0)
```

Comment: What is the logic for Number value ? It is importanrt or it must be sequnece starting from 1 for those characters that have more then one representative ?

Comment: No, the number values don't matter. Actually in my case I have two string columns and I need to select an empty string instead.  I thought this was a good simplification for the question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tba.mychar
-- if tbu.mychar is null, then the letter is not unique
--   when it happens, the letter is not "unique" thus use the number column
--   else use zero for "unique" letters
, CASE WHEN tbu.mychar IS NULL THEN tba.mynum ELSE 0 END AS newnum
FROM mytab tba
LEFT JOIN (
    -- this subquery only returns the letters that don't repeat
    SELECT mychar
    FROM mytab
    GROUP BY mychar
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS tbu ON tba.mychar=tbu.mychar
```

Answer (score 1):

How about ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/701d0/2)):

```
SELECT Q.letter, 
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (query) QQ WHERE QQ.letter = Q.letter) = 1 THEN 0 
         ELSE Q.number
    END AS number
FROM (query) Q
```

Note, replace "query" with the query that generates your first result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub-query:

```
select t1.col1,
  case when t2.cnt > 1 then t1.col2 else 0 end col2
from table1 t1
left join
(
  select count(*) as cnt, col1
  from table1 
  group by col1
) t2
  on t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b3fd9/8)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this using a UNION ALL of 2 separate statements (one for repeated letters and one for letters that only occur once):

```
    SELECT letter, number
    FROM tableName
    WHERE letter IN (
        SELECT letter
        FROM tableName
        GROUP BY letter
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
    )
UNION ALL
    SELECT letter, 0
    FROM tableName
    WHERE letter IN (
        SELECT letter
        FROM tableName
        GROUP BY letter
        HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
    )
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` would be more efficient.